# Javascript not loading with HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to put together a simple maze game using HTML5 and Javascript. I can successfully load the HTML and CSS content onto the page, but no matter what I try, I can't get the JS to load. It's definitely saved as a .html file and i've only been using Sublime text to put it together (but I wouldn't have thought that would have an affect anyway). Just a bit stumped really, so I thought it must be something I've missed in my code. I wasn't sure if I've missed something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title> Maze Game </title>
</head>
<style> 
canvas {
border: 8px double navy;
background: white;
}

img {
    display: none;
}

button {
padding: 3px;
}
</style>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
<img id="sprite" src="sprite.png">
<script>
//these define the global variables for the canvas and the drawing context
var canvas;
var context;

var x = 0;
var y = 0; //positioning of the sprite

var dx = 0;
var dy = 0; //momentum of the sprite at start

window.onload = function() {
    //setting up the canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //Draws the maze background
    drawMaze("maze.png", 268, 5);

    //On key press, run the following function
    window.onkeydown = processKey;
};


var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function drawMaze(mazeFile, Xstart, Ystart) {
    //This loads the maze picture in
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0; //if the face is already moving, stop it
    var imgMaze = new Image();
    imgMaze.onLoad = function() {

        canvas.width = imgMaze.width;
        canvas.height = imgMaze.height;

        //Draws the maze onto the canvas
        context.drawImage(imgMaze, 0, 0);

        //draws the sprite and positions
        x = Xstart;
        y = Ystart;
        var imgSprite = document.getElementById("sprite");
        context.drawImage(imgSprite, x, y);
        context.stroke();

        //sets a short timer for the next frame to be drawn in (10ms)
        setTimeout("drawFrame()", 10); 
    };
    imgMaze.src = mazeFile;
}

function processKey(e) { //e needs to be used for event handling
    //stop the sprite if it's already moving - enables collision
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;

    //condition for the Up arrow being pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        dy = -1;
    }

    //condition for the Left arrow being pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        dx = -1;
    }

    //condition for the Down arrow being pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        dy = 1;
    }

    //condition for the Right arrow being pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        dx = 1;
    }

}

function drawFrame() { 
    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(254,244,207)";
        context.rect(x, y, 15, 15);
        context.fill 


        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        if (checkForCollision()) { 
 (dx/y = 0)
            x -= dx;
            y -= dy;
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
        }
        //Now we can finally draw the sprite!

        var imgSprite = document.getElementById("sprite");
        context.drawImage(imgSprite, x, y);



        if (y > (canvas.height - 17)) {
            alert("Congratulations! You made it!");
            return;
        }
    }

    timer = setTimeout(drawFrame, 10);
}

var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 50); 
var pixels = imageData.data;


for (var i = 0, n = pixels.length; i < n; i += 4) {
//This will get the data/values for one pixel
var red = pixels[i];
var green = pixels [i+1];
var blue = pixels [i+2];
var alpha = pixels [i+3];

//This will invert the colours
pixels[i] = 255 - red;
pixels[i+1] = 255 - green;
pixels[i+2] = 255 - blue;
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); 


function checkForCollision() {

var imgData = context.getImageData(x-1, y-1, 15+2, 15+2);
var pixels = imgData.data;

//Then we need to perform a check, same as above
for (var i = 0; n = pixels.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = pixels[i];
    var green = pixels[i+1];
    var blue = pixels[i+2];
    var alpha = pixels[i+3];
    //now check for the black pixels for a wall
    if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 0) {
        return true;
    } //checks for a greyish colour - possibly the edge of a wall
    if (red == 169 && green == 169 && blue == 169) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false; //there was no collision 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "I can't get the JS to load" mean? Do you have any errors in the console (F12)? Have you done any basic debugging?

Comment: Are you running the code locally or from a server? Which browser are you using? Are there any errors showing up in the developer tools?

Comment: In fact you do have an error. Line 115: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side: the line that says `(dx/y = 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the line 115 error. That wasn't meant to be there. I'm using Chrome 38.0, but I'm running the code locally. There weren't any other errors than that?

Comment: Yes. You should check the console.

Comment: I put your code into http://jsbin.com/qeziwepipozo/1/edit - it reports 9 errors and 7 warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of errors in this code. For example, in this section alone:

(commented where some issues are)

```
    function drawFrame() { 
    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(254,244,207)";
        context.rect(x, y, 15, 15);
        context.fill                   // Missing parentheses and semicolon


        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        if (checkForCollision()) { 
 (dx/y = 0)                        // Equivalent to { dx / (y = 0) }
            x -= dx;               // which both serves no purpose and divides by zero
            y -= dy;
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
        }
        //Now we can finally draw the sprite!

        var imgSprite = document.getElementById("sprite");
        context.drawImage(imgSprite, x, y);



        if (y > (canvas.height - 17)) {
            alert("Congratulations! You made it!");
            return;
        }
    }

    timer = setTimeout(drawFrame, 10);     // timer is not defined anywhere
                                           // also you are calling the function within itself
                                           // with no end condition, so it's an infinite loop
}
```

And on line 48:

```
setTimeout("drawFrame()", 10);
```

You should be passing the function as just the function identifier, not as a string. As such:

```
setTimeout(drawFrame, 10);
```

These are just a few. There are also some logical errors, variables that are defined but never used, and more. In its current state this will not compile.

Also, if only just for clarity's sake, try to define a script type instead of just leaving the tag empty, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some JS
</script>
```

It can be hard when you've been staring at code for hours, but it helps to give each section a slow read-through and think about exactly what the code is doing. You can avoid lots of syntactical and logical errors this way.

I also recommend using a text editor or online interface (JS Bin, JSfiddle, etc.) that has JShint/lint or some kind of code-checking functionality. You can even use http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php and paste your whole code in there.

Comment: Thanks! I de-linted and did a text comparison tool. Looks to be working now.